# Returning a stream from an ASP.NET Core Web API and reading it on the Angular side

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, axios, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an API that allows a user to run a back end process and get the response as a series of text lines. The controller is calling this:

```
public async IEnumerable<string> Execute(Info[] infoArray)
{
    foreach(var info in infoArray)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await ProcessInfo(info);
            yield return result;
        }
        catch(ProcessException e)
        {
            yield return e.Message;
        }
}
```

So `ProcessInfo` can take some time to execute, but I want the UI to have a running update of the results.

So, basically I want the controller to return a stream, and send one string at a time as it evaluates the `IEnumerable`, and then on the Typescript side (I am currently using `Axios.get` requests) get it one string at a time so that I can update a GUI with a running log.

I spent several hours digging around on Google and Stackoverflow and couldn't find a good example to follow. What is the best approach?

Comment: Consider using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events - though ASP.NET Core comes with SignalR which defaults to Websockets (which is more flexible than SSE, but also more resource-intensive). YMMV.

Comment: I don't really want to use Web Sockets or SignalR. For sure in other systems I have seen where you can create an output stream on the response and write to it, while the other end reads from it. This is after all a pretty basic concept in http, it is why Web Pages can be rendered progressively.

Comment: What you’re describing there is what SSE is. However “long loading” HTML pages (late-1990s-style) is not a suitable alternative and easily breaks for many reasons, while SSE is specifically designed to handle adverse network conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller should return an `IAsyncEnumerable<string>` or a `ContentResult` with a specific media type (`text/event-stream`).

You may need to disable request buffering and enable streaming to allow for a continuous flow of data like that

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("stream")]
  public async IAsyncEnumerable<string> StreamData()
 {
   foreach (var info in infoArray)
  {
    try
    {
        var result = await ProcessInfo(info);
        yield return $"data: {result}\n\n";
        await Task.Delay(1000); // Simulate processing time
    }
    catch (ProcessException e)
    {
        yield return $"data: {e.Message}\n\n";
    }
  }
}
```

In Angular service or component, create an `EventSource` instance that connects to the streaming endpoint of API.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StreamService {
 private eventSource: EventSource;

 startStream(url: string): Observable<string> {
  return new Observable(observer => {
   this.eventSource = new EventSource(url);

   this.eventSource.onmessage = event => {
     observer.next(event.data);
   };

   this.eventSource.onerror = error => {
     observer.error(error);
     this.eventSource.close();
   };

    return () => {
      this.eventSource.close();
    };
  });
 }
}
```

Inject the service into component and subscribe to the `startStream` method.
Update your component's view as new data arrives

```
// In your component
 this.streamService.startStream('api/stream').subscribe(
   data => {
   // Update UI here with the incoming data
   },
 error => {
  // Handle errors
  }
);
```